# React three fiber renders the obj with linebasicmaterial even if I set MeshStandardMaterial

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I downloaded an obj model online and loaded it:

```
const obj = useLoader(loader, "PATH_OF_THE_MODEL");
const copiedScene = useMemo(() => obj.clone(), [obj])
const t = useLoader(TextureLoader, texture);
const material = new MeshStandardMaterial({ map: (t as Texture) });
material.roughness = 0.5;
material.metalness = metalness;
if(focused){
    material.color.set('#e16410')
}

copiedScene.traverse((child: any) => {
    if (child instanceof Mesh) {
        child.material = material;
    }
});
```

I have different obj that I render in the same way (they all use the same Component) and everyone but this is correct.
I suppose it's something related to the .obj file itself, the problem is I don't know how to resolve it. The funny thing is that it's correct in every 3d models viewer that I tried but, ofc, https://threejs.org/editor/.

[Here's](https://file.io/J3vHoqLBlY1C) the file